# Why isn't this CTE recognized?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I'm trying to pull in student majors to this sql by using a CTE, but when I try to add the CTE fields, or  join the CTE with an implicit join, which works fine in other queries, oracle throws the error 'invalid identifier'. Any thoughts?

This is only the first part of many unions in this sql but I've seen examples where a CTE works fine with unions so I don't think thats it, and besides that when I run this code without the unions I get the same errors, 'invalid identifier'.

```
with major (pidm, major) as
    (
    select 
        a.sgbstdn_pidm,
        a.sgbstdn_majr_code_1
    from 
        sgbstdn a
    where a.sgbstdn_term_code_eff   = (select
                                        max(b.sgbstdn_term_code_eff)
                                         from
                                            sgbstdn b
                                         where
                                            a.sgbstdn_pidm = b.sgbstdn_pidm
                                            and b.sgbstdn_term_code_eff <= '202004' 
                                            and b.sgbstdn_term_code_eff > '202001')
    )


select --authorized aid
  spriden_id id
  ,spriden_last_name ||', '||spriden_first_name || ' '|| spriden_mi "Name"
  ,major.major "Major"
  ,rpratrm_fund_code "Fund"
  ,rpratrm_period "Period"
  ,rpratrm_offer_amt "Offer"
  ,rpratrm_accept_amt "Accept"
  ,null "Loan Net Orig Amt"
  ,RPRATRM_AUTHORIZE_AMT "Authorized"
  ,rpratrm_paid_amt "Paid"
  ,c.hr "Census Hours"
  ,r.hr "Enrolled Hours"
  ,c.con "Consortium"
  ,b.pbcode "P Budget Code"
  ,b.pbcode_locked "P Budget Code Locked?"
  ,b.b_locked "Budget Locked"
  --,astd.astd "Academic Standing"
  ,s.sap "SAP Code"
  ,s.term "SAP Term"
  ,decode(h.pidm, null, 'No', 'Yes') "Holds"
  ,admit.admit "Admitted?"
from
  spriden
  ,rpratrm
  
  --,(select SGVSTDN_pidm pidm, sgvstdn_astd_desc astd from SGVSTDN where SGVSTDN_term_code = '202003') astd
  
  --admitted?
  ,(select
      sgbstdn_pidm pidm
      ,case 
        when sgbstdn_levl_code like 'N%' then 'No'
        when sgbstdn_levl_code is null then 'No Student Record found this term'
        else 'Yes'
      end admit
    from
      sgbstdn
    where
      sgbstdn_term_code_eff = '202003') admit
  
  --HOLDS
  ,(select
      rorhold_pidm pidm
    from
      rorhold
    where
      to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') <= to_char(RORHOLD_TO_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') 
      and to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') >= to_char(RORHOLD_FROM_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
      ) h
   
   --SAP   
  ,(select
      a.rorsapr_pidm pidm
      ,a.rorsapr_term_code term
      ,a.rorsapr_sapr_code sap
    from
      rorsapr a
    where
      a.rorsapr_term_code = (select max(b.rorsapr_term_code) from rorsapr b where a.rorsapr_pidm = b.rorsapr_pidm and b.rorsapr_term_code <= '202003')) s
  
  
  --Period Budget Code Lock/FREEZE
  ,(select
      rbrapbg_pidm pidm
      ,RBRAPBG_PBGP_CODE pbcode
      ,decode(RBRAPBG_PBGP_CODE_LOCK_IND, 'Y', 'Yes', 'No') pbcode_locked
      ,decode(RBRAPBG_BUDGET_FREEZE_IND, 'Y', 'Yes', 'No') b_locked
    from
      rbrapbg
    where
      RBRAPBG_RUN_NAME = 'ACTUAL'
      and RBRAPBG_PERIOD = '202003'
      and RBRAPBG_AIDY_CODE = '2021') b
  
  
  
  ,(select
      rorenrl_pidm pidm
      ,rorenrl_term_code term
      ,RORENRL_FINAID_ADJ_HR hr
      ,RORENRL_CONSORTIUM_IND con
    from
      rorenrl
    where
      rorenrl_enrr_code = 'STANDARD'
      and rorenrl_term_code like '202003') c
  ,(select
      sfrstcr_pidm pidm
      ,sfrstcr_term_code term
      ,sum(sfrstcr_credit_hr) hr
    from
      sfrstcr
    where
      sfrstcr_term_code like '202003'
      and sfrstcr_rsts_code in (select stvrsts_code from stvrsts where STVRSTS_INCL_SECT_ENRL = 'Y')
    group by sfrstcr_pidm, sfrstcr_term_code) r
where
  spriden_change_ind is null
  and spriden_pidm = rpratrm_pidm
  and rpratrm_aidy_code = '2021'
  and RPRATRM_AUTHORIZE_AMT is not null
  
  and rpratrm_pidm = c.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_period = c.term(+)
  and rpratrm_pidm = r.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_period = r.term(+)
  and rpratrm_period = '202003'
  and rpratrm_pidm = b.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_pidm = s.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_pidm = h.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_pidm = admit.pidm(+)
  and rpratrm_pidm = major.pidm
  
  --and rpratrm_pidm = astd.pidm(+)
  and not exists (select 'asdf' from SGVSTDN a where a.sgvstdn_pidm = rpratrm_period and a.SGVSTDN_term_code = (select max(b.sgvstdn_term_code) from sgvstdn b where b.sgvstdn_term_code <= '202003' and b.sgvstdn_astd_desc is not null and a.sgvstdn_pidm = b.sgvstdn_pidm) and a.sgvstdn_astd_code = 'SU') 
  and (r.hr is not null or c.hr is not null)
  and not exists (select 'afd' from rorstat where rorstat_pidm = rpratrm_pidm and rorstat_aidy_code = rpratrm_aidy_code and RORSTAT_DISB_REQ_COMP_DATE is null)
  and not exists (select 'afd' from rrrareq where rrrareq_pidm = rpratrm_pidm and rrrareq_aidy_code = rpratrm_aidy_code and rrrareq_fund_code = rpratrm_fund_code and RRRAREQ_SAT_IND = 'N')
  --this will exclude those without loans should be a loan only query. if chur is auth but mpn not done, student won't show up
  and exists (select 'asdf' from rlrdlor, rlrdldb where RLRDLOR_PIDM = rlrdldb_pidm and RLRDLOR_PIDM = rpratrm_pidm and RLRDLOR_LOAN_NO = rlrdldb_loan_no and RLRDLOR_AIDY_CODE = rlrdldb_aidy_code
                                                and rlrdlor_aidy_code = rpratrm_aidy_code and RLRDLOR_FUND_CODE = rlrdldb_fund_code and rlrdlor_fund_code = rpratrm_fund_code and RLRDLOR_MPN_LINKED_IND = 'Y')
```

Comment: Maybe I should just turn the CTE in to a subquery in the from clause...

Comment: ANSI-92 is the standard adopted to replace implicit joins *(using `,`)* with an explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That's very nearly 30 years old.  Please ***stop*** using out-dated and error prone syntax from the wrong century.

Comment: It's code I inherited and I don't feel like rewriting 1000 lines of code if I don't have to.  It works FINE without me trying to add this field.

Comment: The major column from the CTE.  I think I figured it out though, forgot to add the CTE to the from clause.

Comment: Please close the question

Answer (score 0):

Adding the CTE to the from clause made it work.  Forgot about that little detail.